# PHP array from xml-file - get unknown object names and attributes

Tags: php, arrays, xml, simplexml

I load a xml-file like this:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('test.xml');
```

Then I created an array:

```
$array= $xml->xpath('//objektart');
```

The content of the array looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [haus] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [haustyp] => ZWEIFAMILIENHAUS
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Now I want to get the **name of the SimpleXMLElement Object** = "haus"
and the **attributes** = "haustyp" and "ZWEIFAMILIENHAUS" for outputtting them on a website.

The values like "haus", "haustyp" and "ZWEIFAMILIENHAUS" can vary, so i cant rely on these "keywords" to access them. Just the method of creating the array from the xml-element stays the same.

Can anyone please point me to the right direction here? I'm stuck for hours testing without any result...

Comment: Can each `objektart` tag have more than one child tag? Can the tags have more than one attribute?

Comment: Hi iainn, thanks for asking! There can only be one child tag. This child tag might have one attribute or none, but not more than one attribute.

Comment: Use a `foreach` loop. And please also include the code that you've tried to use to solve this yourself.

Comment: Hello miken321 Thanks for your answer. I couldn't see how a foreach-loop would help me, because I'm only trying to get the values of even one child tag each time.
But I gave it a try and now I can access the name of the child-tag by using 
`foreach ($xml->objektart->children() as $objektart) {
      print_r((string)$objektart->getName());echo '<br/>';
      print_r((string)$objektartType->attributes()->haustyp);echo '<br/>';
}`
But the _$objektart_ &attr-value can change, so i cant look for the attribute _haustyp_ each time. I'm looking for a way to get the attribute-value "dynamically".

Answer (score 0):

I created a package to simplify xml conversions in php. You can find it here:

https://github.com/mtownsend5512/xml-to-array/blob/master/src/XmlToArray.php

It will allow you to convert your xml like so:

```
$xml = \Mtownsend\XmlToArray\XmlToArray::convert(file_get_contents('test.xml'));
```

Then you may inspect the php array with `print_r($xml);` If attributes are picked up, they will be in an `@attributes` key. You are free to use PHP's many array functions to manipulate and loop over the array.

If you provide more information about your actual xml, I can provide more detailed examples.

Comment: Hi Mark! Thanks for your answer. I tried to use your script but I can't get it to work. I copied your php-script into a new file _xmlToArray.php_  and first tried to call it like your example: `$xml = \includes\xmlToArray::convert(file_get_contents('test.xml'));` , but this did not work. Then I tried to use `require_once('./includes/xmlToArray.php');` and to call it like this `$xml = \includes\XmlToArray::convert($xmlFile);` and this `$xml = XmlToArray::convert($xmlFile);`, but all of this breaks the site.

Comment: Did you change the filename from XmlToArray.php to xmlToArray.php? What is the error you are receiving?

Comment: yes, i named it _xmlToArray.php_, this is why i used the spelling this way in my `require_once`-call. This works so far (i renamed it for testing and by wrong spelling i get an Error 500). So with correct spelling I assume the script gets loaded. The site gets displayed correctly without an error. Referring to your Quick Start at Github I added `$array = XmlToArray::convert($xml);` (CLASS) to my php-script. But then I get an Error 500 again, without any further information. Same with `$array = xml_to_array($xml);` (GLOBAL HELPER)

Comment: Did you try it using the example I gave ``$xml = \Mtownsend\XmlToArray\XmlToArray::convert(file_get_contents('test.xml'));``? This is not a directory reference. It is a namespace reference. The namespace would be the same (if you copied the XmlToArray.php file exactly). So you would first require it, then do ``$xml = \Mtownsend\XmlToArray\XmlToArray::convert(file_get_contents('test.xml'));`` to execute it.